# Process to check for new/deleted tables in database

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, database-administration

Is there any way I can script out the following idea using T-SQL:

I have the start of a script, which identifies tables currently on a database, and their respective row counts, as below:

```
    SELECT o.name AS 'TableName' ,i.rows AS 'Records'
    FROM sys.tables as o LEFT JOIN sys.sysindexes as i
    ON  i.id = o.object_id 
    WHERE o.type IN ('U')
    AND i.indid in (0,1)
```

But I'd like to set something up where I can flag up any new tables which appear on the database (sort of like yesterday vs today) - also, any that have recently been deleted. Almost acting as a 'table log history'.

So the final output would be a list of all current tables + new + deleted (from yesterday).

Cheers in advance.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Also: as of SQL Server **2005**, you should **stop using** the `sysobjects`  view - use the focused catalog view in the `sys` schema - like `sys.tables` or `sys.types`

Comment: are you asking for deleted table count in same format as you have

Comment: Thanks, altered the join and redirected to more appropriate tables as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine from `sys.objects` when a table was created or modified (`create_date`, `modified_date`) but I think you are out of luck from that perspective on deleted tables.

This kind of auditing is best handled by [DDL triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx). You can make create a table like `dbo.ddl_change_log` and populate it with the DDL trigger.